# Microsoft Graph api is returning 401 (Unauthorized) instead of 403 (Forbidden) error code

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Someone has shared below two files with my account:

1. F1 (With edit permission): Since I have edit permission, all the APIs are working correctly for this file.
2. F2 (With view only permission): Since I don't have edit permission, below a few APIs are not working as expected and not returning correct error code:

   1. [CreateLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request): This API is returning 401 (Unauthorized) instead of 403 (Forbidden) error code
   2. [Get permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request): This API isn't returning error but gives all the permissions for the file. Since I'm not the owner of the file, this should return me an error with 403 code.
   3. [Send Invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) and [Delete Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request): These two APIs are working as expected and giving error with 403 response code

More Details: [Expected Error Code Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors)

Please look into this and lemme know if my understanding is not right.

Comment: Could please share what [delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) do you have?